# Issue with Catalyst::View::JSON installation

Tags: perl, catalyst

I have installed the `Catalyst::View::JSON` module in my server.
Then I configured it in my app file

```
use Catalyst qw/View::JSON/;
```

And also created a view file for that JSON.pm with the following contents

```
package Myapp::View::JSON;
use base 'Catalyst::View::JSON';
1;
```

After I restart apache I get the following error:

```
Syntax error on line 1064 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:
Can't locate Catalyst/Plugin/View/JSON.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /home/wesolnsus/public_html/application/lib /usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5 /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 . /etc/httpd) at /usr/local/share/perl5/Catalyst.pm line 2977
```

But when I checked the path  `/usr/local/share/perl5` I can see a Folder named JSON in it.

I am not sure why the issue is occurring as JSON is installed correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Catalyst::View::JSON` isn't a plugin. Don't put it in your plugins list (the list after `use Catalyst`).